# how to disable scrollbars for new frames in Aquamacs Emacs?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

In Aquamacs, I have scrollbars turned off:
`(scroll-bar-mode -1)`.

But when I do New Buffer in New Frame, i.e. <kbd>⌘-N</kbd>, the new frame has a scrollbar. How do I make it so new frames have scrollbars off by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, which you can add to `~/.emacs` or wherever your init script happens to live, should solve this problem by disabling scrollbars on newly created frames, immediately after they're created:

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          '(lambda (frame)
             (modify-frame-parameters frame
                                      '((vertical-scroll-bars . nil)
                                        (horizontal-scroll-bars . nil)))))
```

Works for me in Emacs 24.3 on both Linux and Darwin; Aquamacs is weird, so your mileage may vary, but I doubt it's weird enough to break this.

Comment: This worked! Do you know how I would add a line to disable Aquamacs' tabbar mode? I have `Show Tabs` unchecked but every time I create a new window, Aquamacs turns it back on. I tried adding this line to your code above but it didn't help. `(tabbar-mode nil nil (tabbar))`

Comment: @PeterSalazar Not as such; `<rant class="opinionated">`Aquamacs lasted all of five minutes with me before I trashed it in favor of [this Mac port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port), which is vanilla GNU Emacs 24.3 with (very good) Darwin/Aqua patches, rather than trying to Frankenstein everything into the Aqua school of UI thought, the way Aquamacs does.`</rant>` Have you tried [`(tabbar-mode -1)`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsEmacsCompatibilitySettings) in your init file?

Comment: yup, I do have that line also. It works for a while, until I start creating new frames and new tabs.

Comment: @PeterSalazar I just grabbed a fresh copy of Aquamacs and fired it up to try this out; while I didn't make a systematic study, doing `M-x customize-group RET tabbar RET` and setting 'Tabbar Mode' to 'Off' seems to have done the trick. The value of `tabbar-mode` after I'd done so was `nil`, so it's possible either `(setq tabbar-mode nil)` or just `(tabbar-mode nil)` will have the desired effect, but Customize may be partaking of special magic, too, and I'd thus recommend trying that route if you haven't already done so.